# Purpose of 'then' clause in JS for REST API?

Tags: javascript, rest

I am new to JS and I am trying to understand what this piece of code is doing:

```
$rootScope.addUser = function(userId) {        //1
            $http.post('/addUser', {           //2
                params: {                      //3
                    user_id: userId            //4
                }
            }).then(function(result) {         //5
                $rootScope.userId = undefined; //6
                $rootScope.getUsers();         //7
            });
        };
```

From my understanding (please correct me if I am wrong anywhere):

The 1st line is taking in a userId (not sure if the type is specified...).

The 2nd line is accepting a POST request with the endpoint of /addUser.

Lines 3 and 4 are taking the input from line 1 and setting it to the variable 'user_id' (I'm guessing to be used somewhere else?)

Lines 5 to 7 I'm guessing will be executed at the end of this request, but I don't know where 'result' is coming from.

But why is line 6 setting the userId to undefined?

This code interacts with some Java backend, but I don't understand what the purpose of some of these lines are.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises

Comment: The code is not _accepting_ a POST request, it's _sending_ one. The "result" will come from the server when it returns a response to the post request. Who knows why the user ID is being set undefined? That must be something specific to this particular application. P.s. you should read about AJAX and Promises to aid your overall understanding

Comment: "not sure if the type is specified" ... JavaScript is weakly typed so no, it isn't, and can't be

Comment: @ADyson - I would venture a guess that #6 is for differentiating between no response and empty response.

Comment: "'I'm guessing to be used somewhere else?)"... correct, sort of. It gets placed into the body of the request and is thus sent to the server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The 1st line is taking in a userId (not sure if the type is specified...).

Yes, this declares a function that takes a `userId` as a parameter. In JavaScript, we don't have to declare the types of our variables.

> The 2nd line is accepting a POST request with the endpoint of /addUser.

The 2nd line **makes** a POST request to the endpoing `/addUser`.

> Lines 3 and 4 are taking the input from line 1 and setting it to the variable 'user_id' (I'm guessing to be used somewhere else?)

These lines are creating the data to send in the POST request. That data is then used by whatever program is running on the server.

> Lines 5 to 7 I'm guessing will be executed at the end of this request, but I don't know where 'result' is coming from.

These lines are executed when the response comes back from the server. `result` is the body of that response.

> But why is line 6 setting the userId to undefined?

By setting `$rootScope.userId = undefined`, this guarantees that the key `userId` exists in the object referred to by `$rootScope`. I assume that the author did this just to avoid accessing the key later without defining it first.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Since JS is weakly typed and let's say a Java backend system receives this request, how will it know what type 'userId' should be when it is passed in the method? Is it possible for this value to be null if, say, in the backend system it states that the variable type of 'userId' is Integer?

Comment: Also, I am assuming that the number of parameters in line 1 should always be the same as the number of parameters set inside the 'params' bracket or will there every be a case where this is not true?

Comment: @mrnoobynoob Things that are sent to a server are generally also untyped. It's up to the server (java in this case) to absolutely ensure that things are of the correct type.

Comment: @mrnoobynoob "weakly typed" is a phrase that is tossed around that isn't clearly defined. More accurately, I would call JavaScript "dynamically typed", meaning that we don't specify types in our code but they are determined as the program runs.

Comment: @mrnoobynoob The requirements for the data that is passed in the request is entirely defined by the backend. It is possible, although unlikely, that a `null` value is accepted. If it is not, then the backened will return an error response.

Comment: "I am assuming that the number of parameters in line 1 should always be the same as the number of parameters set inside the 'params' bracket" No, that need not be the case. It entirely depends on how you represent the data in your JavaScript code before packaging it to send with the request.

Comment: @Evert I think it is inaccurate to say that data sent to a server is "untyped". For example, JSON clearly defines types and how they are represented in a string format.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice true, but JSON doesn't force a specific property to be for example a number. Even if an API expects a property to be a number, a client can send something completely different. That's what I meant with my comment.